# SSIS execution from asp.net error 64bit excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, ssis, 32bit-64bit

**Background**

I've implemented an asp.net web application which executes an SSIS package from disk. This works when running from visual studio in debug, but once released to the server complains about 64 bit SSIS as per error below.

I've seen numerous posts about resolutions, but am unsure about the most apporpriate fix for my scenario. I have full access over the web server and asp.net c# application code, limited access over the database server for this release.

**The error:**
*SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_EXCEL_NOT_SUPPORTED: The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS, as no OLE DB provider is available. SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER*

**C# Code**

```
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        string result = string.Empty;
        string dtsErrors = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            pkgLocation = packagePath;
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

            //Add any errors to string for notifying user
            foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in pkg.Errors)
                dtsErrors += " " + local_DtsError.Description;

            result = pkgResults.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            result = exception.Message;
        }
```

**Potential Resolutions (please help with recommendations)**

- Run SSIS as a 32 bit process (How do I do this and will it work in my situation?)
- Install 64 bit drivers for excel/access and use a sql stored proc with openrowset to get my data instead of SSIS. I'm not sure about this one, do I need the drivers on the database server and web server? Also I'd need to get the db admin to turn on ad hoc queries which they may not be ok with. Here's the driver I got working locally, but then it was already working locally the original way..
  http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/
- Any other fix I haven't mentioned, these seem like rough hacks..?

Comment: For sure you have mix up 32bit with 64bit libraries (and they can not run together). Find what is what and correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is to run the iis application pool in 32 bit mode.

Nopte that after I got this working in my asp.net page I realsised that this only worked from within a browser on the server hosting the site. Here is my post related to getting it working from a broswer on any client hitting this server: [SSIS package from ASP.net does not work on client but does on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829664/ssis-package-from-asp-net-does-not-work-on-client-but-does-on-server#comment19068707_13829664)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on Excel driver, by default Excel driver is 32bit. And if you are trying your application on 64bit operating system, then it will definitely throw an error.

To resolve this go to *Project properties > Debugging > Debug Option* 
 and set *Run64bitruntime* to *False*. See more [here](http://ssistutorials.blogspot.co.nz/?view=flipcard).

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you are executing your package, but there is a property that you can set pre execution to force 32bit runtime.  Within the Integration Services Catalogs (SSIS 2012), its under the advanced tab upon execution where there is a 32-bit runtime check box.

[image]

As its Excel, you are going to have to run as 32bit as there the 64bit Excel driver is not supported.  This may help you [SSIS 32 and 64 Bit - Todd McDermid](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html#!/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html)

[picture source](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/24/running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment.aspx)