# SSIS package from ASP.net does not work on client but does on server

Tags: iis, permissions, ssis

**Description Of Environment**

I have an SSIS task which executes from asp.net, the package gets data from excel files over UNC path and puts the data into a sql server databaase . I have deployed the SSIS to file system, it has windows authentication database connections and the IIS user has database access. I can log in as the AppPoolUser I have used to host the web application and open/modify the files in question so those basic permissions are there. Web App is compiled in x86.

**When it works:**

- When run from web app in browser on server under my user or appPool user
- When logged in as me on server running through BIDS
- When logged in as AppPoolUser on server running through BIDS
- When run from scheduled task on server using AppPoolUser

**When it doesn't work:**

- When run from client browser i.e. not the machine that has IIS hosting the asp.net app

**My Question**

What is different about the client and server and how do I make it work? I was under the impression that when running the web app all connections go through the AppPool User so it should behave the same on any machine server included?

**The Error returned to client browser**

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\myserver\My folder\myfile.xlsx'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.". SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "MyExcelFileConnection" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. component "Excel Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. One or more component failed validation. There were errors during task validation.

**c# Code running SSIS Package**

```
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        string result = string.Empty;
        string dtsErrors = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            pkgLocation = packagePath;
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

            foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in pkg.Errors)
                dtsErrors += " " + local_DtsError.Description;

            result = pkgResults.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            result = exception.Message;
        }
```

Comment: "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\myserver\My folder\myfile.xlsx'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't help me, you've simply copied the error from my post. Can you give direction on how to resolve this error? Am I missing something simple?

My question is why would it work when run from a browser on the web server but not from a client? I was under the impression both browsers would be running under the app pool user which I have explicitly set to a domain user.

Comment: Use a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out who has the file open, and with which access.

Comment: OK, the file is not open. I have added the excel server file location to the trusted excel groups but no luck with this either. Integration services is not installed on the client but this is only required on the server I believe.

Comment: When you say "the client", what are you saying? Is this code running in a web browser, or are you talking about back-end ASP.NET code running on a server, in IIS?

Comment: The SSIS import c# shown in the original post is being run in code behind for an aspx page.

Comment: Regarding the client - this is a different machine to that hosting IIS which I open a browser in. This "client" does not have IIS or excel installed but the server with IIS that hosts does have these installed and when using a browser on this server everything works.

Comment: Turn on SSIS logging and see who the package is running as?

Comment: I still don't get this. The codebehind _must_ be running on a machine running IIS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21042/discussion-between-john-and-john-saunders)